# Fixed div disappearing on scroll left Css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I looked at many answers here on SO but none worked for me.

Below are the posts I have looked before posting this question.

> jquery fixed div on scroll-down
>
> jquery fixed div on scroll, smooth movement
>
> jquery fixed div on scroll, bottom boundary
>
> How to manage css left property for fixed div
>
> fixed div position on scroll is not working in all conditions
>
> Absolute DIV inside a relative DIV inside a fixed Div disappears on scroll
>
> Sticking a fixed div on scrolling down

For this purpose I have created a fiddle that shows my problem :
 [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/HFjU6/2806/)

My problem there is the login span disappearing on zooming (I can't see it on scroll right)

```
#fixedContainer
{
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.login
{
    float: right;
}
```

I would prefer a CSS solution but am OK with a Javascript solution too.

Comment: I can see it after zooming and scrolling right in your fiddle.

Comment: If this will help , im using latest firefox , and i cant see the login span .

Comment: I can see it in Firefox too. If you are referring to the case when "login" is past the screen on the right, you cant see it because you have `position: fixed;`. You may want to try using `position: absolute;`.

Comment: @RahulDesai No rahul , i dont want use absolute , i want use fixed and the login span appears on zooming. Its not difficult for me to use absolute, i asked about fixed .

Comment: I dont understand whats wrong. Looks alright to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these `css` attributes to your `#fixedContainer` selector:

```
overflow-x: auto;
max-width: 100%;
```

Comment: Wonderful :) , i have changed in my fiddle max-width with 90% . thanks alot :) . if i knew that i should not lose 2 days on that :) .